# How do I solve this problem of reading a CSV file in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

**The sample java code that I am using is follows**

```
package com.fooflink;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;

public class CSVTestV2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   
    ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    String filePath = "/Users/sayan.r/Downloads/sample.csv";

    // Read the CSV file from local
    env.readTextFile(filePath)
        .map(new CSVParser())
        .print();

    // Execute the Flink job
    env.execute("CSV Test V2");
  }

  // Custom MapFunction to parse the CSV data
  public static class CSVParser implements MapFunction<String, Tuple3<String, String, String>> {

    @Override
    public Tuple3<String, String, String> map(String line) throws Exception {
      String[] fields = line.split(",");

      String id = fields[0];
      String event_name4 = fields[4];
      String from_state5 = fields[5];

      return new Tuple3<>(id, event_name4, from_state5);
    }
  }
}
```

**The output that I get while running this java code in my local Intellij IDE is as follows:**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50866:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/sayan.r/workspace/foobar-flink/target/classes:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-core/1.16.1/flink-core-1.16.1.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-annotations/1.16.1/flink-annotations-1.16.1.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-metrics-core/1.16.1/flink-metrics-core-1.16.1.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-asm-9/9.2-15.0/flink-shaded-asm-9-9.2-15.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-jackson/2.12.4-15.0/flink-shaded-jackson-2.12.4-15.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.24.0/kryo-2.24.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-1.2.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.21/commons-compress-1.21.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-guava/30.1.1-jre-15.0/flink-shaded-guava-30.1.1-jre-15.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.32/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-force-shading/15.0/flink-shaded-force-shading-15.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-java/1.16.0/flink-streaming-java-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-file-sink-common/1.16.0/flink-file-sink-common-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-runtime/1.16.0/flink-runtime-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-rpc-core/1.16.0/flink-rpc-core-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-rpc-akka-loader/1.16.0/flink-rpc-akka-loader-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-queryable-state-client-java/1.16.0/flink-queryable-state-client-java-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-hadoop-fs/1.16.0/flink-hadoop-fs-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-netty/4.1.70.Final-15.0/flink-shaded-netty-4.1.70.Final-15.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-zookeeper-3/3.5.9-15.0/flink-shaded-zookeeper-3-3.5.9-15.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.24.0-GA/javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.8.3/snappy-java-1.1.8.3.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/lz4/lz4-java/1.8.0/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-java/1.16.0/flink-java-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.7.6/chill-java-0.7.6.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-clients/1.16.0/flink-clients-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-optimizer/1.16.0/flink-optimizer-1.16.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.5.0/commons-cli-1.5.0.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-csv/1.16.1/flink-csv-1.16.1.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-files/1.16.1/flink-connector-files-1.16.1.jar:/Users/sayan.r/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/snakeyaml-1.29.jar com.fooflink.CSVTestV2
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001056bf6b9, pid=31026, tid=0x000000000000b703
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_282) (build 1.8.0_282-bre_2021_01_20_16_06-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.282-b00 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# [thread 47619 also had an error]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x5666b9][thread 48387 also had an error]
  Unsafe_GetInt+0xcd
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
[thread 46339 also had an error]
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/sayan.r/workspace/foobar-flink/hs_err_pid31026.log
Compiled method (nm)    3778 1760     n 0       sun.misc.Unsafe::getInt (native)
 total in heap  [0x000000010dd95450,0x000000010dd957a0] = 848
 relocation     [0x000000010dd95578,0x000000010dd955b8] = 64
 main code      [0x000000010dd955c0,0x000000010dd957a0] = 480
Compiled method (nm)    3778 1760     n 0       sun.misc.Unsafe::getInt (native)
 total in heap  [0x000000010dd95450,0x000000010dd957a0] = 848
 relocation     [0x000000010dd95578,0x000000010dd955b8] = 64
 main code      [0x000000010dd955c0,0x000000010dd957a0] = 480
[thread 49923 also had an error]
[thread 82691 also had an error]
[thread 49159 also had an error]
[thread 80131 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

What could be the reason for this?

However when I am using the following java code the program works like a charm.

```
 public void execute() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    String filePath = "/Users/sayan.r/Downloads/sample.csv";

    CsvReaderFormat<IndiaBins> csvFormat = CsvReaderFormat.forPojo(Pojo.class);

    FileSource<Pojo> source =
        FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(csvFormat, Path.fromLocalFile(new File(filePath))).build();
    DataStream<Pojo> stream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
        "csv-source");

    stream
        .map(new IncrementMapFunction())
        .addSink(sink);

    env.execute();
  }
```

I wanted to understand the reason why one works and why the other one throws a SIGSEGV error.

Comment: Perhaps there's a line in the input file that doesn't have enough comma-separated fields?

Comment: Have used the same sample csv in both the cases. Works when I am using env.from Source() and does not work when using env.readTextFile()